# is there anyway I can screen record react native app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, screen-recording

Please, I need any information on how I can screen record view or any other component on react native just like react-native-view-shot for images

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-media-recorder, https://www.npmjs.com/package/record-screen, among many others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `npm i react-native-screen-recorder`. This will help screen record in react native

Comment: I don't want to record the full screen of the app. I just want to record the camera screen because I added a text overlay and if I record with camera button it won't record the text I added

Answer (score 0):

If you want to record everything including everything you see in the screen, you might want to try this.

[react-native-record-screen](https://github.com/yutasuzuki/react-native-record-screen)